# bugcode_usb_driver BSOD after clean install

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod, windows-installation

I installed Windows 8.1 on a USB drive with WinToUSB but whenever I boot it it it shows me a BSOD with the error message `bugcode_usb_driver`. All the solutions I've found online say to update the drivers from Windows, but I can't access it.

I haven't been able to do the first time setup yet since it doesn't boot and no new files have been created on the drive.

---

**What I've done (or tried to do)**

- Plug in the drive to all the different USB slots available
- Find logs inside `C:\windows\minidump` (nothing there)
- Booting in safe mode (Mouse, keyboard and Wifi not working even if booted with "allow networking" on)
- Reinstall Windows (Doesn't help)
- Use Windows 10 instead of Windows 8 (Doesn't help)

**What I'll try to do**

- Installing drivers from another computer

Comment: @magicandre1981 I get it after installing. The installation goes well

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've tried it in both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports

Comment: share (Onedrive share link) the dmp files from **C:\windows\minidump**

Comment: @magicandre1981 How can I get to the files if my Windows doesn't boot?

Comment: boot a linux live DVD and upload the files there

Comment: I won't have access to the computer until tomorrow. However I've checked the files in the drive from another computer and there is no **minidump** file or folder inside **C:/Windows**. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: even after rebooting no file is generated under C/Windows and it shows that the last edit was in 2014.